# JavaScript Array Push Missing Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

This function will take an array and chunk it into separate arrays, create an offset at the beginning and wrap that in another array. The problem I have is not all of the numbers from the original array (arr1) are included in the chunks. You can see the output in the link I have provided below. It misses out numbers 5, 13, 21, 29 and 30. Can anyone explain why this happens?

```
function chunkifyArray(input, chunkSize, offset) {

    const output = [];

    let tmp = offset ? new Array(offset).fill('') : [];

    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        if (tmp.length < chunkSize) {
            tmp.push(input[i]);
        } else {
            output.push(tmp);
            tmp = [];     
        }
    }

    return output;
}

var arr1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30'];
console.log(chunkifyArray(arr1, 7, 3));
```

https://jsbin.com/zucaguvoti/edit?js,console

Comment: Because you never push those values - you empty tmp insead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you never push those values - you empty tmp insead…  Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    tmp.push(input[i]);
    if (tmp.length == chunkSize) {
        output.push(tmp);
        tmp = [];     
    }
}
```

Edited to ensure the last chunk is pushed onto output...

Comment: This would still miss the last chunk.  The push should come first.

Answer (score 0):

I changed little bit your code to get to the desired result. You can use the `%` operator as well as remember to add the last portion at the end of the `for` loop:

```js
var data = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30'];

function chunkifyArray(input, chunkSize, offset=0) {
  let output = [], tmp = [];
  input = new Array(offset).fill('').concat(input);
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    tmp.push(input[i])
    if (i && i%chunkSize == 0) {
        output.push(tmp);
 tmp = []
    }
  }
  output.push(tmp);  // add the remaining ones
  return output;
}

console.log(chunkifyArray(data, 7, 3));
```

You could `chunk` an array with **ES6** and `Array.reduce`:

```js
const data = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30']

const chunkBy = (arr, by=2, offset=0) => new Array(offset).fill('').concat(arr)
 .reduce((r,c,i) => (i%by==0 ? r.push([c]) : r[r.length-1] = [...r[r.length-1], c], r), [])
  
console.log(chunkBy(data, 7, 3))
```

When not in `compact` form this would look like:

```js
const data = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30']

const chunkBy = (arr, by=2, offset=0) => {
   arr = new Array(offset).fill('').concat(arr)
   return arr.reduce((r,c,i) => {
     if(i%by==0)
       r.push([c])
     else 
      r[r.length-1] = [...r[r.length-1], c]
     return r
   }, [])
}
  
console.log(chunkBy(data, 7, 3))
```